If $x_n<x_{3n+5}+x_{n+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ diverges
Let $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $x_n<x_{3n+5}+x_{n+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}$ for every $n\ge 0$. Prove that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n$ is divergent.
I think that the idea here is to somehow use a comparison test. Let $S_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of our series, i.e. $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n x_k.$$
Then I think that a good idea might be to look at $S_{3n+5}$ for $n\ge 0$. This is a sum of $3n+6$ terms. We can pair $2n+2$ of them, i.e. the ones with the indices $3k+5$ and $k+\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor$ for $k=\overline{0, n}$, and apply the inequality in the hypothesis to them, thus obtaining an inequality of the type $$S_{3n+5}\ge S_n+\text{something}.$$
Now I think that we should be able to bound that "something" in terms of some $S_j$, but I am unable to see a way forward and I am not sure if this actually works.

Hint: $ 3n + 5 \neq m + \lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$ for any $n, m$.  $\quad$ Show that the sum is greater than $x_1$, $2x_1, 3x_1, 4x_1, 5x_1, \ldots$, hence diverges.

@Calvin thanks, so I should somehow prove that $S_n\ge nx_1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$? I agree that $3n + 5 \neq m + \lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$, but how does this help? Should I try to succesively apply the inequality in the hypothesis for $n=1, 2, ...$ and sum them up?

Yes, that's the goal. $\quad$ As a detour, suppose the condition is $ x_n < x_{2n} + x_{2n-1}$. Using that condition, how can we show that the sum is greater than $2 x_2, 3x_2, 4x_2, 5x_2, \ldots$, hence is divergent? (In this case, $x_n = 1/n$ satisfies the condition). Now, apply those ideas here.

@CalvinLin is it a good idea to try to prove this by induction like this: we let $P(n)$ be the assertion $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_k\ge nx_0$, it is clear that $P(0)$ is true, then we assume this holds for some $n$ and then we show it also holds for $n+1$? I am starting to get a feeling of how the process you described works, I would basically truncate the series at a greater index term at the $(n+1)$th step than the $n$th and then the hypothesis would finish the proof.

It is a good idea to give things a try. You can edit the post to show your work.

@CalvinLin I am still hazy on writing down the details. I would like to be able to say something like "since $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_k\ge nx_0$, then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N} x_k\ge nx_0$ for sufficiently large $N$", but I don't think that is actually true, right?

Not quite. I encourage you to work through the other example first to see how it works. The idea there is that we show $ \sum_{i = 2^k + 1 } ^ { 2^{k+1} } x_i > \sum_{i = 2^{k-1} + 1 }^ { 2^k }  x_i > \ldots > x_2$. Hence, the sum of all terms can be bounded below by $ x_1 + x_2 + x_2 + x_2 + x_2 + \ldots$, thus diverges. $\quad$ How can we modify that argument to this problem?

@CalvinLin ok, I see how the other example works now: to get $\sum_{i = 2^k + 1 } ^ { 2^{k+1} } x_i > \sum_{i = 2^{k-1} + 1 }^ { 2^k }  x_i$ you pair together the first two terms in the LHS, you apply the hypothesis, you keep doing this and after summing up everything you get precisely your inequality. In the present problem I should now figure out what the bounds of the sum, i.e. $2^k+1$ and $2^{k+1}$, should be replaced with.

Yes in the meta sense, but not exactly that specific idea. You're unlikely to find such nice bounds, since the terms tend to jump all over the place.  $\quad$ So look at say $ x_2 < x_3 + x_{11} < x_{4} + x_{14} + x_{16} + x_{38} < \ldots$. If we can prove that all of the indices are distinct, then we can bound the sum by $x_2 + x_2 + x_2 + x_2 + \ldots$.

@CalvinLin thank you, now I have understood how this goes and why it matters that all of those indices are distinct. What I am not sure is how to formalize this. I thought that I should look at $S_{2^n}$, use your inequality repeatedly for $2^{j}$ terms where $1\le j\le n-1$ and I think that this is enough to conclude that $S_{2^n}\ge n x_2$, which yields the desired conclusion. But I am unsure how to rigorously write this down.

@CalvinLin sorry for tagging you, but I am still trying to rigorously write down your approach because I am not really convinced that the current answer is actually correct and I am sure that your idea works. I am convinced that the claim I made in the last comment is true, i.e. we have $S_{2^n}\ge nx_2$ for every $n\ge 1$ if we keep iterating the inequality you wrote and group together $2^j$ terms in $S_{2^n}$ for $1\le j \le n-1$. What I am still missing and I would like to be able to write down is precisely the inequality I am applying at the $j$th step of this process.

Alma's solution works, per my comment. It's much simpler than mine, so I'd encourage you to try to understand it. $\quad$ I've undeleted my solution. I'm not confident that your claim is true, because we do need the $x_{3n+5}$ term, so it might be true that $ S_{4^n} \geq n x_2$ for $n> N$ large enough. However, like I said, "You're unlikely to find such nice bounds, since the terms tend to jump all over the place".

@CalvinLin thank you for undeleting your solution, this certainly helped me to properly understand your approach. As for Alma's solution, I am really confused how to justify his $\bigstar$ inequality since as per our discussion considering finite sums and taking the limit doesn't work, and I also do not really understand why his last inequality is strict...

Suppose $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n < \infty$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n
&\overset{\bigstar}\ge \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{3n+5} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{n+\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(x_{3n+5}+x_{n+\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\right)\\
&> \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n
\end{aligned}$$
Contradiction. Therefore, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n = \infty$. $\square$

$\bigstar$ The inequality holds because in the RHS we are adding up terms without repeating indices.
In fact, for all $a, b\in\mathbb Z$, we have $3a+5\ne b+\left\lfloor\dfrac b2\right\rfloor$, as
$$3a+5\equiv 2\pmod 3
\quad\text{and}\quad
b+\left\lfloor\dfrac b2\right\rfloor\equiv 0, 1\pmod 3.$$

Oh nice, that's more direct than how I was approaching it.

@Alma Arjuna thank you, that is really nice. I have two questions. First, to see that $\bigstar$ holds we can note that $\sum_{k=0}^{3n+5} x_k\ge \sum_{k=0}^n x_{3k+5}+\sum_{k=0}^n x_{n+\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}$ because the indices do not repeat as you said and then we let $n\to \infty$, right? I wanted to make sure how to justify this without directly writing series. Second, why is the last inequality strict? If we use the hypothesis I can only see why we have $\ge$, not $>$.

@AlmaArjuna thank you. Well, yes, I agree that in my statement that inequality is strict, bur in general if for two convergent sequences $(a_n), (b_n) $ we have $a_n<b_n$ for every $n$, then we only have $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \le \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$, and this also applies to series. Or is strictness of the inequality preserved for series? I don't know...

@QuantumBoy I apologize, I made a mistake in my last comment. Writing the inequalities using finite summations will not solve the problem because, as you have noticed, strict inequalities stop being strict when you apply a limit. This approach would only prove $$\sum_{n=0}^{3N+5} x_n > \sum_{n=0}^N x_n$$ which is true for any series of positive real numbers.

@AlmaArjuna okay, then how do we actually justify the inequality you wrote using infinite summation? And what about the last one that is not actually strict, is there a way to make it strict?

@QuantumBoy This solution could be presented using my terminology as $ \sum x_i  = \sum_{i } x_{f(i) } + \sum_{j} x_{g(j) } + \sum_{ k \neq f(i), g(j) } x_k  > \sum_{i} x_{f(i) } +   x_{g(i) }   > \sum x_i $. Hence, we have a contradiction if the sum is finite. $\quad$  As I mentioned, the hope for cleanly defined bounds is too naive, and so we need a more general description.

@CalvinLin Thank you for rephrasing this into your notation, this makes more sense to me. With the risk of being way too annoying, could I ask why the inequalities are strict? The strictness of these inequalities still eludes me...Thank you for taking so much time to help me!

1/ The first is strict because we're excluding terms not of the form $f(i), g(j)$, like $x_1$  2/ The second is strict because of the given condition $x_{f(i)} + x_{g(i) } > x_i$.  $\quad$ We only need one of those to be strict, for this proof to work. Typically, the first inequality is likely to be strict, since $x_1$ shouldn't be involved again.

@CalvinLin thank you so much! Now it is really clear to me why the first one is strict and that is enough for the proof to work. You are a real life saver!

Define $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, f(n) = n + \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, and $ g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, g(n) = 3n+5 $.
Observation: $f, g$ are increasing functions.
Observation: $f^{-1} $ and $g^{-1}$ exist (on the appropriate domain).
Lemma: $f(n) \neq g(m)$ for any $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$.
Proof: For $n = 2k$, $f(2k) = 3k$.
For $n = 2k+1, f(2k+1) = 3k+1$.
So $f(n) \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{3}$ and $g(m) \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, hence they can never be equal.
Lemma: The integers $ f(2), g(2)$ and $ f(f(2)), f(g(2)), g(f(2)), g(g(2)),$ and $ f(f(f(2))) , \ldots $ are all distinct from each other.
Proof: Suppose not. The lemma states that the last operation must be the same. The observation allows us to take the inverse of the operation. We repeat this process, until at least one of the numbers is 2.

If only one of the numbers is 2, then we have $2 = f\ldots (2) > 2$ or $ 2 = g\ldots (2) > 2 $ is a contradiction.
If both numbers are 2, then by following the chain of operations, we have the same expression.

Corollary: The sum diverges.
Partition the integers into $ S_0  =  \{2 \},$ $S_1 = \{ f(2) , g(2) \}$, $S_2 = \{ f(f(2)), f(g(2)) , g(f(2)), g(g(2)) \}$, $S_3 = \{ f(f(f(2))) , \ldots \}, \ldots$. We may have some integers left over.
Show that for each set $S_k$, $ \sum i \in S_k x_i > x_2$.
Hence, the partial sum is greater than $ k x_2$ for any integer $k$, thus it diverges.
Note: How important is distinctness in the lemma?
If we have $f(g(n)) = g(f(n))$, then the sum could be finite.
EG Consider $ f(n) = n+1 , g(n) = n+2$ or that $x_n < x_{n+1} + x_{n+2}$.
Then, with $x_n = 1.5^{-n}$, the condition is satisfied, but $ \sum x_n = \frac{ 1.5^{-1}  } {  1 - 1.5^{-1} } = \frac{ 1 } { 1.5 - 1 } = 2$ is finite.
